# Constant expression contains invalid operations plugin class properties visibility

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have declared a private variable to hold a custom post type arguments array. I can't understabd why when I try to activate the plugin I get always this error: `Constant expression contains invalid operations`.

Is there a fix?

code example

```
<?php
class CustomPostType {

public $services = array( ... );


 public function init()
 {
  register_post_type( 'services', $this->services );
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you include the code?

Comment: Here's a link that might be helpful, but we need to see some code to help you. Also, since this is a PHP question and not something tied directly to WP, it would probably be closed anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations

Comment: To be more clear, I have putted a public variable inside a post type class declaration. This is why I've got this problem, this is not normal, because if I declare a public or provate variable inside a class and i use the `$this->variable` to call it, it usually not throw an error...